# Get a Checkbox in an AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog

I added an `AlertDialog`, in which a `Checkbox` is, but if I tap on the `Checkbox`, it doesn´t get a hook. I also added another `Checkbox` below the `AlertDialog` and this one gets a hook by clicking on it. I think it has something with `setState()` to do, but I don´t know. Does anybody knowes a solution? Thanks in advance

```
ListTile(
                title: Text("Test"),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.fitness_center),
                onTap: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text("Test"),
                        content: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Checkbox(
                                  value: checkBoxValueTheraband,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      checkBoxValueTheraband = value;
                                      exerciseChooser();
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                Text("Theraband"),
                              ],
                            ),),);});})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *setState* you are using in the *showDialog* is not "owned" by it, which means it will not rebuild anything in it and actually update the state of the parent that "owns" it. Instead, you give it its own `StatefulBuilder` that has its own *StateSetter setState* as a parameter. Now when *setState* is used it will invoke the *builder* and change the state of anything in this widget.

```
 content: StatefulBuilder(
             builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return  Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Checkbox(
                                  value: checkBoxValueTheraband,
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                    setState(() { 
                                   checkBoxValueTheraband = value;
                                      exerciseChooser();
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                Text("Theraband"),

                              ]),

                            ]);

                   }
               )
```